# Is there a way to dynamically paste values to table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a 3 tables in my database. They are

Table_1

Table_2

General_table

```
select * from General_table

id  Col1 
1   34
2   35
9   34
```

I have written a dynamic query where in I need to extract contents in Table_1 and Table_2.
So

```
declare @fil nvarchar(max) = '34'
declare @new_var nvarchar(max) 

set @new_var = 'select id from General_table where col1 =' + ''''+@fil+''''

print('select * from Table_'+@new_var+'')
```

When I execute this, I get below output

[image]

But the expected output is to be dynamically calling Table_1

Expected output

```
select * from Table_1
```

Similarly, when I pass @fil as 35, the expected output should be

```
select * from Table_2
```

Comment: I'm struggling to undersand how the code above is expected to get to your expected result - why are you printing a *select* statement and aggregating a variable already containing a *select* statement to it? Is the `1` for `Table_1` supposed to be the ID value from `General_table` where `col1` is 34?

Comment: yeah right. When 1 is returned, it should be Table_1. Similarly, when 2 is returned, then it should be Table_2

Comment: That does not answer the question above where I asked if it's supposed to be the ID value that gets concatenated to your string

Comment: Yes, the ID value gets concatenated to my string

Comment: You're concatenating the `@fil` variable that you assigned `'34'` to - what is the intention here - you're not expecting your SQL string to have the value 34 in so why are you doing this?

Comment: No No. I am concatenating, ID value returned when @fil = '34'  . So here the ID returned is 1. Now, I need to concatenate this to Table_ and it becomes Table_1. Do you get my point?  I already mentioned that there are 2 tables in my DB. Table_1 and Table_2. Instead of hardcoding these tables, I need to dynamically call this . Make sense?

Comment: Your `print` is simply printing the result of you concatenating 2 string literal values - the text string in `@new_var` is not going to be executed - nowhere above are you using *exec* or *sp_executesql*

Comment: print is only to see what is the result I am getting. Even if you put exec, it will not work. You are not getting my question I guess :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code, and the accepted answer, are both product specific.

Comment: @jarlh it's pretty obvious given the screen shot.

Comment: @stu, if you are using that one I suppose it is... But I have never used whatever it is.

Comment: @jarlh I guess that's fair enough - odd though how your highest-scoring sql-related tag is SQL Server and you don't recognise a screen shot from the product :)

Comment: @stu. I have used dbfiddle.uk's SQL Server service - but they all look the same there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following snippet help build the SQL String you are expecting?

```
declare @sql NVarchar(max), @fil Int = 34;

select @sql = Concat(N'Select * from Table_', Id)
from General_Table
where col1 = @fil;

print @sql;
/* exec sp_executesql @sql; */
```

Comment: perfect and this is what I wanted :)

Comment: Sorry I am adding minor request here. I have edited my question and I have added 2 values (1 and 9) for 34. Now, I need to take max of it( it is 9). So the final table when @fil = 34 should be Table_9 and not Table_1. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Try this CONCAT(N'Select * From Table_', MAX(Id)).  With that said - can you explain why you need to do something like this?  Why do you have the same tables that have different _N on them?